# Dialog is not a function Jquery and .net core

Tags: jquery, .net, .net-core

I am deleting using confirmation dialog in jquery and .net core

its giving me error that Dialong is not a function

I have included the Jquery first

```
   <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Mine jquery functions

```
    <script>
        $(function () {

         $('a[id*=btnDelete]').click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).parent()[0].id;
            $('#confirmDialog').data('

id', id).dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    var id = $(this).data("id");
                    window.location.href = '/Employees/Delete/' + id;
                },
                "Cancel": function (e) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is Button

```
   <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" role="dialog" data-target="confirmDialog">
```

This is Confirmation Dialog

```
   <div id="confirmDialog" title="Remove Assignmnet" hidden>
         <p>Do you want to save changes </p>
       </div>
```

Comment: Correct, it's not part of jquery (and obviously not part of .net-core, which is server-side).  Your code looks like it's expecting a *bootstrap* dialog - include the js and css for bootstrap and you should be good to go.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: "It's not working" - helpful diagnostic there.  Generally the modal needs a bit more html, have a read of: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this type of error is that you missed any script which is important for the dialog function to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very late reply but It can help other people on similar issues.
I guess if you remove this part it will work.

> $('#confirmDialog').data('
> id', id).dialog('open'); return false;});

I have a very similar solution that I am using in my project.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btnDeleteUser" title="Delete" data-value="@item.Id" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5C9;</i></a>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm Choice" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>This user will be deleted. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

```
    $(function () {
                var id = 0;
                $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteUser', function () {
                    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
                    id = $(this).attr("data-value");
                });

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete User": function () {
                        console.log("delete user clicked.");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $.ajax({

                            traditional: true,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Management")',
                            data: { DeleteUserId: id }, //" {DeleteUserId:'" + id + "'}",
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log("success");
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                console.log("error");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        console.log("I clicked no.");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I hope it helps someone. Cheers!